# how scatter function work in python for plotting graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, svm, scatter

How does the scatter function work here? I would like to know what `c=Y` means and what is `X[:,0]` and `X[:,1]` in the following code.

```
#make_blob is data set

X, Y = make_blobs(n_samples=500, centers=2, random_state=0, cluster_std=0.40) 
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=Y, s=50, cmap='spring')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `make_blobs` refers to `sklearn.datasets.make_blobs`:

`X` represents a dataset of features and `Y` represents the corresponding labels (targets). Each column in `X` therefore represents a single feature.

`X[:, 0]` performs indexing on `X` in the form `[row, column]`, where `:` means "everything". Therefore, the combined expression means "take every row from X in the column with index 0" (i.e. the first column).

Similarly, `X[:, 1]` takes every row from X in the second column.

Together, these can be taken as the x- and y-coordinates of your scatterplot.

Passing `c=Y` tells the function that you want the points to be coloured based on the corresponding value of `Y`. Therefore, all points with `Y=0` will be of one colour, and all points with `Y=1` will be of another colour.